# How to increment the value of the unique constraint column value in ORACLE

Tags: oracle, identity

How to increment the value of the unique constraint column value in ORACLE, in the select statement.

For example, in a table 'BILLING_TABLE' - column BLNG_Sk is the unique key (Autoincremented).

So while inserting a new record into the BILLING_TABLE, for the column BLNG_SK we need to give the value (Which is the increment by 1 from the present max value.)
For example, if BLNG_SK max value is 12321.

new record should be 12322.
how to achieve this in Oracle?

Comment: If it's autoincremented, why do you need to set it to your own value? In fact, if it's an identity column (Oracle 12.1 or later) you can't assign your own value to it.

Comment: you meant to say that....do you want to achieve this dynamically..i mean will you provide 12321 manually or you want the code to pick it up?

Answer (score 0):

Oracle has a `SEQUENCE` object which provides the functionality you require.

You create one using the `CREATE SEQUENCE` SQL statement.

The Oracle documentation provides all the required information and the documentation is available via Oracle's Web site.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a sequence and a trigger. This is the case when you provide the value manually.

CREATE SEQUENCE dept_seq START WITH 12322;

**Trigger definition:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER dept_bir 
BEFORE INSERT ON BILLING_TABLE
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
  SELECT dept_seq.NEXTVAL
  INTO   :new.id
  FROM   dual;
END;
/
```

Comment: Why `select from dual` rather than a straightforward assignment?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are on Oracle 12.1 or later, define it as an identity column and do not pass any value when inserting:

```
create table testtable
( test_id number generated always as identity
                 constraint testtable_pk primary key
, othercol varchar2(10) );

insert into testtable (othercol) values ('Demo');

select * from testtable;

   TEST_ID OTHERCOL
---------- ----------
         1 Demo

insert into testtable (othercol) values ('Demo #2');

select * from testtable;

   TEST_ID OTHERCOL
---------- ----------
         1 Demo
         2 Demo #2
```